# Is it possible to use persistent connections in rclone?

Tags: rclone

I am trying to use `rclone` to upload millions of small files to a storage provider. Using the default settings (`--transfers 4`) works fine, but it's a waste of the server bandwidth.
Each file is approx 1-2KB. My bandwidth is ~50MBps.

I tried using `--transfers 1000`, which got me the following error from the provider:
[image]

Their support suggested making **persistent** connections, but I could not find such an option in `rclone`.

I looked at the `tpslimit` option (setting it to `1.6`), but that would effectively cap me
at max 100 **files** per **minute**. I want to cap my connections, not the files transferred.

Is this something I can accomplish either with an rclone option or with a system tweak?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Dropbox remote in rclone, create your own [Dropbox ID](https://rclone.org/dropbox/#get-your-own-dropbox-app-id) and use this:

```
rclone sync /path/to/your/local/folder YourDropboxRemote: --dropbox-batch-mode async --transfers 64 --checkers=64 --fast-list --size-only --tpslimit 12 --tpslimit-burst 12 -Pv
```